# How to use Google Visualization to create a table with Sub Columns?

Tags: javascript, python, html, css, google-visualization

I need to create a Table in the following format using Google Visualization :

A |   B   |   C   |   D   |
       | 1 | 2 | 1 | 2 | 1 | 2 |

Where 1,2 are the Sub Headers of B, C, D. I am currently using a table with Headers as A, B1, B2, C1, C2, D1, D2. But I would like to divide them into sub headers as shown above.

Please let me know whether this is feasible using GVis. If feasible, How can it be done. Otherwise, Please let me know if there are any workarounds for achieving this.

Please let me know if there are any clarifications required in the question.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a feasible way, but you probably won't like it.

First you make your chart using the subheaders (so you have `"", "", "1", "2", "1", "2", "1", "2"`).

Then you make a separate chart below it, make it zero height, no grid lines, no vertical axis, no legend, no nothing (but make sure it has the same `chartWidth` as the above chart). In the chart below you create a chart using `"A", "B", "C", "D"` as your categories, and no data (`null, null, null, null`). Your labels will automatically align to be centered on each pair of top values.

However, if you really only have 1 value for the "A" series, then they won't line up (since the labels can't be distributed evenly). You can either create a blank series, or create a double-thick line for A (by putting the same value in both columns), or something tricky like that.

If you are willing, you could alternatively write Javascript to place floating text boxes below the horizontal axis labels with some fancy CSS.

Comment: Basically, this is a probable workaround. I guess using CSS would be my best option then.